# How to disable the Geo back up policy for an Azure datawarehouse through PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, data-warehouse

How Can I disable the Geo back up policy for an Azure datawarehouse while it's being created or after using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data warehouse is `Gen1`, try the command as below, specific the `-State`  with `Disabled`.

[`Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseGeoBackupPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqldatabasegeobackuppolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

If your data warehouse is `Gen2`, you cannot, geo-backups for `Gen2` as data protection is a built-in guaranteed.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/backup-and-restore#geo-backups